# query to return specific date from teradata timestamp(6)

Tags: sql, teradata

How can i search for a particular date for eg: '2013-10-22' from teradata timestamp(6) field?

```
sel * from table A
where date = '2013-10-22';
```

I tried the above query which is throwing error. Please help!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You may try like this:-

```
sel * from table A
where date = date '2013-10-22';
```

Since in ANSI standard form (must be preceded by the keyword DATE)

Check out [this](http://www.teradataforum.com/l081007a.htm)

Comment: Can i also know how can i group by only with date from timestamp?

Comment: @RRR:- Didnt get that what you are asking? Could you ask another question!

Comment: If i want to group by with respect to timestamp column, only wrt date. for eg: when i perform group by createddate, it gives all records separately because the time in each value is different. i want to group all similar dates together irrespective of the time in the timestamp fields

Comment: @RRR:- I dont think so that is possible however you can group by on your date column!

Answer (score 1):

And more formally:

```
select * 
from table A
where cast(timestamp_column as date) = date '2013-10-22';
```

I'm guessing that you were just showing an example, because I don't think you can have a column named `date`; it's a reserved word. The keyword "**date**" above is how you specific an ANSI date constant and is not related to the "date" function.

Comment: The unexpected thing is: you don't even have to do the CAST. When a Timestamp is compared to a Date it is automatically casted to a date. I don't know if this is based on Standard SQL, but when i investigated a supposed bug i found this defined in the manuals.

Comment: Using functions in the where clause like this tends to slow down production.  This is magnified if you are applying the function to an indexed field.

Comment: @dnoeth Yes, I sort of remember that, but I hate writing code that uses default conversions.  Same reason why I always use the `date` modifier in front of a date string.  Its not really needed but it makes it much clearer to me what is going on.

Comment: If i want to group by with respect to timestamp column, only wrt date. for eg: when i perform group by createddate, it gives all records separately because the time in each value is different. i want to group all similar dates together irrespective of the time in the timestamp fields

Comment: @RRR I think your "group by" thing deserves a separate question. Ask another, and be sure to show an example of what you want. Saying "group by with respect to timestamp" does not make much sense.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
where YourTimestampField >= {d '2013-10-22'}
and YourTimestampField < {d '2013-10-23'}
```

Comment: If i want to group by with respect to timestamp column, only wrt date. for eg: when i perform group by createddate, it gives all records separately because the time in each value is different. i want to group all similar dates together irrespective of the time in the timestamp fields