# sql teradata filtering on date - database version Teradata 15.10.06.02 and provider version Teradata.Net 15.11.0.0

Tags: sql, date, filter, teradata

my table has a date column. its data type is date. I confirmed it by going to `table name>>columns` and it says `MTH_END_DT [DATE, Not NULL]`

I want to filter my data for a particular date. If I put a condition `where MTH_END_DT =  '6/1/2018'` I get an error `select failed [3535] A character string failed conversion to a numeric value.`

I followed this [page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19523643/query-to-return-specific-date-from-teradata-timestamp6). I used `where MTH_END_DT =  date  '6/1/2018'` and i get an error `syntax error invalid date literal`

I tried `where cast(timestamp_column as date) = date '2013-10-22';` something like this and it throws error too

How should i filter my data?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There's only one reliable way to write a date, using a *date literal*, `date 'yyyy-mm-dd'`

```
where MTH_END_DT = DATE '2018-06-01'
```

For a Timestamp it's

```
TIMESTAMP '2018-06-01 15:34:56'
```

and for Time

```
TIME '15:34:56'
```

In SQL Assistant it's recommended to switch to Standard SQL format `YYYY-MM-DD` in *Tools-Options-Data Format-Display dates in this format*

Comment: Thumbs up for the answer! :)

Answer (score 4):

I did have the similar problem when I was filtering a particular date for my query with Teradata. First method I tried was putting 'DATE' term as the following:

`WHERE saledate = DATE'04/08/01'` but this did not solve the problem.

I then used an approach I stumbled upon when surfing, finally it worked.

`WHERE extract(year from saledate)=2004 AND extract(MONTH from saledate)=8 AND extract(DAY from saledate)= 1` [source](https://datascience-enthusiast.com/SQL/teradata_1.html)

I think this really should not be this long, but it worked.

Comment: There's only one reliable way to write a date, using a date literal, `date 'yyyy-mm-dd'` and your 1st method simply doesn't use this format.

Comment: Thank you for the input. I tried this way `WHERE saledate = date'2014-08-01'` got no data this time. Is this because my date column use / between year/month/day ? I do not know why I am still not getting the correct result with this `date`  literal.

Comment: What's the exact datatype of `saledate`? `WHERE saledate = date'2014-08-01'` should work for `date` and also `timestamp` (it's automatically converted to a date for comparison).

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me it’s most likely you have input the date format incorrectly? Maybe it includes a time by default.

For example

where MTH_END_DT = ‘2013-10-22-00:00:00:00’

Comment: I copied one of the cell values and it is `8/1/2017`

Comment: @Ni_Tempe: When you *copy a cell value* you probably mean SQL Assistant which formats the date based on local settings. It's recommended to switch to Standard SQL format `YYYY-MM-DD` in *Tools-Options-Data Format-Display dates in this format*